# Override Devise's TokenAuthenticatable::authenticate! function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, token

My User class is :token_authenticatable. I want to override the function Devise::Strategies::TokenAuthenticatable.authenticate! function with my own function. What is the best way to do that?

Other question is, if I want to override the TokenAuthenticatable class with MyTokenAuthenticatable class to override a couple of functions, what is the best way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new Strategy i.e.

> Devise::Strategies::MyTokenAuthenticatable

It can be a copy of

> Devise::Strategies::TokenAuthenticatable

that has your necessary changes

Comment: where exactly should I place these strategies? I tried placing this is my lib/devise/strategies folder but it gives uninitialized error.

Comment: You should require the strategy in your devise initializer. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009941/devise-ignore-my-custom-strategy and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503827/devise-ignoring-custom-strategy for other pitfalls