# I need simple but complete instructions for implementing a Devise authentication strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am trying to write a devise authentication strategy to authenticate against an existing legacy API. I have no database, so I cannot migrate Users from some existing source. I want to do something like:

http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/

However, after following those instructions, Devise refuses to call my authentication strategy. I've tested this by attempting to insert puts calls into my RemoteAuthenticatable modules...

Peter.

EDIT adding code as requested.

app/models/User.rb:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :id

  include ActiveModel::Validations #required because some before_validations are defined in devise
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks #required to define callbacks
  extend Devise::Models

  define_model_callbacks :validation #required by Devise

  devise :remote_authenticatable
end
```

lib/remote_authenticatable.rb (Note the puts I've inserted to get some poor-man's tracing).

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module RemoteAuthenticatable
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      #
      # Here you do the request to the external webservice
      #
      # If the authentication is successful you should return
      # a resource instance
      #
      # If the authentication fails you should return false
      #
      def remote_authentication(authentication_hash)
        puts "In Devise::Models::RemoteAuthenticatable.remote_authentication()"
        # Your logic to authenticate with the external webservice
      end

      module ClassMethods
        ####################################
        # Overriden methods from Devise::Models::Authenticatable
        ####################################

        #
        # This method is called from:
        # Warden::SessionSerializer in devise
        #
        # It takes as many params as elements had the array
        # returned in serialize_into_session
        #
        # Recreates a resource from session data
        #
        def serialize_from_session(id)
          resource = self.new
          resource.id = id
          resource
        end

        #
        # Here you have to return and array with the data of your resource
        # that you want to serialize into the session
        #
        # You might want to include some authentication data
        #
        def serialize_into_session(record)
          [record.id]
        end

      end
    end
  end

  module Strategies
    class RemoteAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def valid?
        puts "In Devise::Strategies::RemoteAuthenticatable.valid?()"
        true
      end

      #
      # For an example check : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb
      #
      # Method called by warden to authenticate a resource.
      #
      def authenticate!
        puts "In Devise::Strategies::RemoteAuthenticatable.authenticate!()"
        #
        # authentication_hash doesn't include the password
        #
        auth_params = authentication_hash
        auth_params[:password] = password

        #
        # mapping.to is a wrapper over the resource model
        #
        resource = mapping.to.new

        return fail! unless resource

        # remote_authentication method is defined in Devise::Models::RemoteAuthenticatable
        #
        # validate is a method defined in Devise::Strategies::Authenticatable. It takes
        #a block which must return a boolean value.
        #
        # If the block returns true the resource will be loged in
        # If the block returns false the authentication will fail!
        #
        if validate(resource){ resource.remote_authentication(auth_params) }
          success!(resource)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and the code I added to config/initializers/devise.rb

```
  require 'remote_authenticatable'  

  config.warden do |manager|
     manager.strategies.add(:remote, Devise::Strategies::RemoteAuthenticatable)
     manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :remote
  end

  Devise.add_module :remote_authenticatable, :controller => :sessions,  :route => { :session => :routes }
```

Comment: Show some of your code?

Comment: were you able to fix this ? I'm getting the same issue

Comment: I broke down and rolled my own. Sorry Sandeep.

Comment: @user1498830 Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7324533/32816

Comment: I did indeed. You'll notice that I declare valid? and have it return true. The valid? method wasn't being called either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the call to

```
manager.strategies.add
```

And instead adding this call at the end of your strategy file

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:rememberable, Devise::Strategies::RemoteAuthenticatable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the remote_authenticable.rb (model ) into app > models > concerns > devise > models, 
and inserted a debugger statement to check it's correctly called

```
def remote_authentication(authentication_hash)
  debugger
  false 
  # Your logic to authenticate with the external webservice
end
```

the remote_authenticable.rb (strategy ) into  lib > devise > strategies

and added the warden block into devise.rb ( initializers )

```
require "devise/strategies/remote_authenticable.rb"

config.warden do |manager|
  manager.strategies.add(:remote, Devise::Strategies::RemoteAuthenticatable)
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :remote
end
```

And it runs ...

Answer (score 0):

in config/initializers/devise.rb you wrote this

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.strategies.add(:remote, Devise::Strategies::RemoteAuthenticatable)
  manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :remote
end
```

now make another file in same directory namely "remote.rb" and add something like this

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:remote) do 
 def valid? 
 true
end 

def authenticate! 

  if params[:user]
    user = User.find_by_login_name(params[:user][:login_name])

    if user && user.account_status != "active" # add your own checks here for authentication 
      fail
      halt! #after this succes no other authentication will process
    end
  else
    fail
  end 
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the same tutorial this worked for me:

Breaking remote_authenticatable code into:
/lib/devise/models/remote_authenticatable.rb and /lib/devise/strategies/remote_authenticatable.rb

In config/initializers/devise.rb I added

```
require 'devise/orm/active_record'
require "devise/strategies/remote_authenticatable"
require "devise/models/remote_authenticatable"

Devise.add_module :remote_authenticatable, :controller => :sessions, :route => { :session => :routes }
```

and under Devise.setup:

```
config.warden do |manager|
 manager.strategies.add(:remote, Devise::Strategies::RemoteAuthenticatable)
 manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :remote
end
```